# if init function failed, should we add retry logic in init function or just let the service reload

Tags: go, web

sometime we need to init some gloabl resource in golang init function such database connections.

```
func init(){
  db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
  if err != nil {
    panic("failed to connect database")
  }
}
```

if the init failed, the deamon will reload the service.
should we do somethine like below:

```
func init(){
  db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
  if err != nil {
    panic("failed to connect database")
  }

  db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
  if err != nil {
    panic("failed to connect database")
  }
}
```

I think reload the service may be a good for web service

Comment: Well, that _really_ depends. If your infrastructure tends to result in frequent glitches where retrying helps establishing a connection than retrying reduces the time your code is not operating (as retry probably is faster than crash and restart). You probably should wait a bit (not just a handful of microseconds but much less than a crash/restart cycle takes) before retrying. If something is fundamantaly wrong with the Config you will detect this later as you retry a broken, unworkable Config several times. There is no hard answer.

Comment: The best answer to your problem depends on how frequent which type of problems actually occur in your infrastructure, what SLAs your service has to fulfill, how you are monitoring and alerting on this type of problems, etc. pp.

Comment: in fact, if init failed, the service will not be discovered by any other service.